# Why do we say, in problems, that the surface is smooth which is why it is frictionless?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

While reading Principles of Physics,I came across the line in friction chapter-
If two highly polished and carefully cleaned metal surfaces are brought together in a very good vacuum,they cannot be made to slide over each other.

Obviously because friction is so high we just can’t, then why do we assume surfaces to be smooth and then say the surface is frictionless?

Also, if you’re walking on water, why is it easy to slip if on smooth surface it actually becomes a very good strong attraction between surfaces? though this is just an optional question but my first one is the main one.

Comment: Obviously, when two rough surfaces slide past each other, they tend to get "hooked" on each other.  So smooth is pretty much a necessary condition for low-friction sliding.  It is not sufficient though.  As pointed out in your reading, two clean blocks of metal can "cold weld".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If two highly polished and carefully cleaned metal surfaces are brought together in a very good vacuum,they cannot be made to slide over each other.*

This isn't really friction. If two sets of the same type of atom are brought close enough together, how do the atoms 'know' that they should be on part A or part B? This is called cold welding and isn't normally a problem unless you work on high vacuum or high precision optics.

*Obviously because friction is so high we just can’t, then why do we assume surfaces to be smooth and then say the surface is frictionless?*

Because in this case 'smooth' is one of those silly crossword clue statements in introductory physics to tell you to ignore friction, without telling you to ignore friction (sorry one of my pet peeves)

*Also, if you’re walking on water, why is it easy to slip if on smooth surface it actually becomes a very good strong attraction between surfaces?*

Because the 'surfaces' aren't really touching. Your feet are touching water and the ice is touching water. It is the thin layer of water moving over itself that provides the low level of friction. This is the same principle as putting a thin layer of oil between moving mechanical parts

Comment: A smoother surface doesn't always mean more static friction, it depends a lot on what the interfacing materials are.  Smooth metal surfaces will have less friction that rough ones for a pretty large extent.  The issues OP runs into with two near perfectly flat metals is a bit different because if the surfaces can get too close they can bond.  You can still polish surfaces to dramatically reduce the friction in many interfaces.  Flat metals can cold weld, which is more of a chemical issue.

Comment: Didn’t get the smooth vs rough part...

Comment: I get the metal  Cold-weld thing that it’s a bond issue but isn’t this that friction is due to perpendicular attractions of uneven surfaces and if the surface is made smooth,obviously there will be more attractions to increase friction,I get the smooth(in questions) part,cold-weld part(we will have to bring them literally very closer to each other than normal things around us) just the metal when smooth has less friction,like that just contradicts and explains the writer of questions...

Comment: Sorry that was more an answer to the title than the question - will re-write to be more useful answer

Answer (score -2):

well the answer is not as simple as you might think.
what do you mean by frictionless? A surface that has no roughness, then it will have more friction(static) than a rough surface, as there will be more electromagnetic forces working between both the surfaces, so frictionless surface is not possdible. And for smooth surfaces, the writer simply wants to ignore friction.